# MongoDB find() to only return results when a certain parameter is set

Tags: mongodb

Looking through the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) I can't find anything that matches this query. For instance, say I want to do a lookup of the collection `products` which only returns results for which the parameter `maker != undefined`. Example set:

```
[{
    name: 'Obj1',
    maker: 'Maker1'
}.{
    name: 'Obj2'
}.{
    name: 'Obj13',
    maker: 'Maker2'
}]
```

In the example above, only objects 1 and 3 should be returned.

From the docs, I thought maybe `projections` might be what I was looking for but this just returns certain fields, rather than limiting results to whether certain field exist.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) operator to select documents that contain a particular field:

```
db.products.find({maker: {$exists: true}})
```